# Links between differing notions of "pseudo-measure"'; or, why that name?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

(A [pet peeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_peeve) of mine is Mathematicians from field X noticing that field Y uses terminology which is very close to that from field X, and assuming there are Mathematical links.  This question *might* be along these lines).

In the literature around Fourier transforms and multipliers on Abelian groups, the term "pseudomeasure" occurs.  For example, [Section 4.2 of Larsen's book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0oTuCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA100&ots=60ihmuQpt5&dq=pseudomeasure&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false) defines a "pseudomeasure" to be bounded linear functional on $A(G)$ the Fourier algebra of $G$.  Here $G$ is a locally compact abelian group and so $A(G)$ is identified with $L^1(\widehat G)$ by the Fourier transform, and so pseudomeasures are simply the "Fourier transforms" of elements of $L^\infty(\widehat G)$.  I *guess* the terminology arises because genuine measures on $G$ give rise to functionals on $A(G)$ by integration.  (I have to say that my *personal* intuition is that this view is not wildly helpful.)  The terminology has then been copied for non-abelian groups, and generalisations to $L^p$ spaces; see for example [Chapter 4 of Derighetti's book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DtX4cEDqWv0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false).

By contrast, in [Section 6.3 of Folland's book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z-GYCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA177&ots=hY5KiKnxSx&dq=pseudomeasure&pg=PA175#v=onepage&q&f=false) a psuedomeasure is a continuous linear functional on $C_{00}(G)$ the space of compactly supported continuous functions with the inductive limit topology.  Such objects, *to me*, do seem to be more closely linked to measures.  Their use here is in generating unitary representations, by way of the notion of a positive definite pseudomeasure.

My questions are:

> Is there a genuine mathematical link between these two notions, or are they just superficially similar?
>
> I would be interested in the history of why "psuedomeasure" for the dual of $A(G)$: who first used this term, and can one guess at the motivation for it?

Comment: Hi Matt, on the question of who used this terminology first, my first not-completely-wild guess is Rudin, but I haven't looked up the literature (yet)

Comment: As for the intuition, I think this might be because of the classical history of people trying to see when you can recognize a measure (with various properties) from properties of its Fourier coefficients. Most of these results are negative, of course; but one can look at distributions on the circle and define their Fourier coefficients, and certainly to be a measure you must have bounded Fourier coefficients, so maybe people wanted a name for distributions with bounded Fourier coefficients...